# Bootstrap 5 "Horizontal form" does not display validation errors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using Bootstrap 5 example for placing the labels and input fields horizontally.

I force the error classes to test the placement of the error.

Whatever I tried, the error does not display. The field has the Red border and the error icon but no error message is displayed.

If the fields are not horizontal like this, the error is displayed:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="password" aria-describedby="passwordError">
     <div id="passwordError" class="invalid-feedback">
          <strong>Error here</strong>
     </div>
</div>
```

So how do you display the error on a horizontal style please?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="m-4">
  <form method="POST" action="#" id="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control is-invalid" aria-describedby="passwordError" autocomplete="current-password">
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <span id="passwordHelp" class="form-text">
        Must be 8-20 characters long.
      </span>
      </div>
      <div id="passwordError" class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>Error here</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation is displayed using a sibling selector i.e. it looks like: `.is-invalid ~ .invalid-feedback` so the `is-invalid` class needs to belong to an element which is a sibling of the validation feedback.

This should work:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="m-4">
  <form method="POST" action="#" id="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto is-invalid">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control is-invalid" aria-describedby="passwordError" autocomplete="current-password">
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <span id="passwordHelp" class="form-text">
        Must be 8-20 characters long.
      </span>
      </div>
      <div id="passwordError" class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>Error here</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

As far as I am aware no one has actually documented how validation is intented to work for horizontal forms.